# Refreshing the richtextbox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am using a rich text box in my win forms application. i am searching for a perticular text and highlighting the selected text. Say i am searching for the string "he_llo" so "he_llo" is highlighted. I am correcting it to "hello". I am calling the highlight function in the button click.If the string is corrected to hello,it  should not highlight at that time. But it is highlighting .

```
 private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Validate();

        }
```

public void Validate()
    {
        string[] words;
        object[] items = chklbErrorlist.CheckedItems.OfType().ToArray();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < errorList.Count; i++)
    {
        //errorList.Add(items[i]);
        if (rtbFileDisplay.Text.IndexOf((errorList[i].ToString())) != -1)
        {
            wordToFind = errorList[i].ToString();
            index = rtbFileDisplay.Text.IndexOf(wordToFind);
            lstErrorList.Items.Add(index.ToString());
            while (index != -1)
            {
                rtbFileDisplay.Select(index, wordToFind.Length);
                rtbFileDisplay.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                index = rtbFileDisplay.Text.IndexOf(wordToFind, index + wordToFind.Length);
                lstErrorList.Items.Add(index.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

    #region "Special Char"
    foreach (string exp in RegularExpSpChar)
    {
        int pos = 0;

        char ch = exp[1];
        words = null;
        words = rtbFileDisplay.Text.Split(ch);

        pos = words[0].Length;

        Regex myregex;
        if (ch.Equals('.'))
        {
            string expr = @"^\.+[a-zA-Z]";
            myregex = new Regex(expr);
        }
        else
        {

            myregex = new Regex(exp);
        }

        for (int index = 1; index < words.Length; index++)
        {
            string line = ch + words[index];
            bool isexist = myregex.IsMatch(line);
            if (isexist)
            {
                rtbFileDisplay.Select(pos, 1);
                rtbFileDisplay.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                rtbFileDisplay.Select(pos, 1);
                rtbFileDisplay.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            }
            pos = pos + line.Length;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region "Special"
    foreach (string exp in RegularExpSpecial)
    {

        int pos = 0;
        char ch = exp[2];
        words = null;
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'i': tagtype = "</i>";
                highlightlen = 5;
                break;
            case 'b': tagtype = "</b>";
                highlightlen = 5;
                break;
            case 's': 
                if(exp[3] == 'u' && exp[4] == 'p')
                {
                    tagtype = "</sup>";
                    highlightlen = 7;
                }
                else if (exp[5] == 'n')
                {
                    tagtype = "</span>";
                    highlightlen = 8;
                }
                break;
            case '8': 
                if(exp[1] == '#' && exp[4] == '2' && exp[5] == '1')
                {
                    tagtype = "&#8221;";
                    highlightlen = 8;
                }

                else if (exp[1] == '#' && exp[4] == '1' && exp[5] == '1')
                {
                    tagtype = "&#8217;";
                    highlightlen = 8;
                }
                break;
            default: break;
        }


        words = Regex.Split(rtbFileDisplay.Text, tagtype);

        pos = words[0].Length;

        Regex myregex;
        myregex = new Regex(exp);

        for (int index = 1; index < words.Length; index++)
        {
            string line = tagtype + words[index];
            bool isexist = myregex.IsMatch(line);
            if (isexist)
            {
                rtbFileDisplay.Select(pos,highlightlen);
                rtbFileDisplay.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;

            }
            pos = pos + line.Length;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

where pos is the index of he_llo and highlighten is the length of he_llo.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You are telling it to Highlight and it is highlighting.

Comment: I am searching for a perticular text say Hello . It highlights . I changed it to hell . At that time it sholud not highlight but its highlighting.

Comment: I am using the indexof method . The textbox is not refreshing after i do edit

Comment: post how do you get pos and highlightlen variables, maybe you do not recalculate them after changing text?

Comment: `I am calling the highlight function in the button click`.  You forgot to click the button.  Or call that function from the TextChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably just have to highlight all of the text and set the selectionbackcolor to white.